# Proper logging configuration to disable django error emails

Tags: django, error-handling, sentry

I just got sentry working in my environment and I tried tweaking my logging to make it stop sending error emails, but it still is and I don't understand why. My logging config is:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s (%(pathname)s %(funcName)s): "%(message)s"'
        },
        "simple": {"format": "%(levelname)s %(message)s"},
        "django.server": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.ServerFormatter",
            "format": "[%(server_time)s] %(message)s",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "null": {"level": "DEBUG", "class": "logging.NullHandler",},
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "simple",
        },
        "log_file": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "filename": "/var/log/courtlistener/django.log",
            "maxBytes": "16777216",  # 16 megabytes
            "formatter": "verbose",
        },
        "django.server": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "django.server",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        # Disable SuspiciousOperation.DisallowedHost exception ("Invalid
        # HTTP_HOST" header messages.) This appears to be caused by clients that
        # don't support SNI, and which are browsing to other domains on the
        # server. The most relevant bad client is the googlebot.
        "django.security.DisallowedHost": {
            "handlers": ["null"],
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.server": {
            "handlers": ["django.server"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        # This is the one that's used practically everywhere in the code.
        "cl": {"handlers": ["log_file"], "level": "INFO", "propagate": True,},
    },
}
```

Is there a missing piece here? I don't know how that'd possibly send emails. Is there another config variable I should be thinking about?

**UPDATE**: One thing I've noticed is that I get *plaintext* error emails now instead of the HTML ones I used to get. This changed when I tweaked the logging config, but I have no idea why and Googling it doesn't seem to reveal anything.

Comment: Have you tried setting `disable_existing_loggers` to `True`? Also, the emails get sent to whatever is set to `ADMINS`, and that's the only thing that setting does, so you could also try removing that.

Answer (score 3):

Django setups a [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/logging/#default-logging-configuration) `mail_admins` handler, which you can't simply replace in the `handlers` section, so if you want to get rid of it you need to overwrite the `handlers` in the root logger:

> All loggers except django.server propagate logging to their parents, up to the root django logger. The console and mail_admins handlers are attached to the root logger to provide the behavior described above.

```
LOGGING = {
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': [],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },

}
```

[edit] fixed wrong statement about overwriting the handler class, sadly it doesn't work as expected, seems to be hard-coded in some way (too busy to look it up in the django code base).

Comment: So I set my logger to: `"mail_admins": {"class": "logging.NullHandler"},`, and I'm still getting emails. [Here's the latest version](https://github.com/freelawproject/courtlistener/blob/master/cl/settings/10-public.py#L487-L546). Any ideas?

Comment: @mlissner: If you run a django-shell (via python manage.py shell), what does `import logging` and then  `logging.getLogger('django').handlers` give you? Is there a non-null handler? You said you are using Sentry, are you sure the emails are not sent by Sentry? :)

Comment: I played around with my local logging settings, actually it's not enough to just overwrite the handler... sorry for the wrong answer regarding that, going to edit it. Only way to get rid of it is to overwrite the root logger's handlers

Comment: I gave that a go and it seems to work, though I set handlers to `['console']`, which is closer to the [default configuration](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py). Is there any risk the above change will have bad side effects?

Comment: OK, yes, I've confirmed that this nukes a lot of logs, at least in dev. Is there a way to avoid that? I'm utterly lost at this point as to what works and how. All I want is the emails to stop.

Answer (score 2):

I have Django 3.2 and ADMINS=[] in settings and I ended up here because the "mail_admins" handler was blowing out the memory limit trying to format emails it wasn't going to send.

A couple of things that might help future people:

1: the logging_tree package is your friend, run `python manage.py shell -c "import logging_tree; logging_tree.printout()"` to get a baseline, then run it after every change and compare the output to the baseline.

2: Handlers are baked to the loggers when the config runs. Djangos default config runs before yours. So you can't override the "mail_admins" handler in your logging config, it's already been baked to the "django" logger. You can override the "django" logger but that will reset all the config on that logger and the ones below it.

3: So I did this dirty thing in settings.py which worked really well: `log.DEFAULT_LOGGING["handlers"]["mail_admins"]["class"] = "logging.NullHandler"` This kills it before Django's logging config gets loaded. It will probably break on a Django update, but it should break loudly.

```py
from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING

# ...

DEFAULT_LOGGING["handlers"]["mail_admins"]["class"] = "logging.NullHandler"
LOGGING = {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: In your `3:`, where does `log` come from ? To be able to do `log.DEFAULT_LOGGING...`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `LOGGING` config looks (almost, see the end) fine to me. There are a few other things I can think of.

Perhaps you made the changes but not everywhere, you may have other apps, celery processes, staging deploys etc. running somewhere that you've forgotten about.

Perhaps something else (I'm not sure what...) is configuring this logging handler. If this is the case, you can disable the existing loggers:

```py
LOGGING = {
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    ...
}
```

This isn't a very good idea though, disabling other people's loggers, so as an alternative you can disable it in another way.

The `ADMINS` setting defines the email addresses to send the errors to, so you can disable it by just setting this to an empty list:

```py
ADMINS = []
```

This should be relatively safe as sending error emails is the only thing this setting is used for - unless you or a third party app are using it.

You can also be sent emails not of server errors, but of 404 errors. Make sure your `MIDDLEWARE` does not contain `BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware`. There is also a similar setting to `ADMINS` for this, but it's called `MANAGERS`:

```py
MANAGERS = []
```

You should also check the [default logging config](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py#L17-L63), to make sure you haven't missed something when creating your own `LOGGING` dict.

One more thing I've noticed, when plugging your `LOGGING` config into a project is that the configuration doesn't parse correctly for me, because the value of `maxBytes` should be an int, not a string. So you could also try changing:

```py
"log_file": {
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
    "filename": "/var/log/courtlistener/django.log",
    "maxBytes": "16777216",  # 16 megabytes
    "formatter": "verbose",
}
```

to:

```py
"log_file": {
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
    "filename": "/var/log/courtlistener/django.log",
    "maxBytes": 16777216,  # 16 megabytes
    "formatter": "verbose",
}
```

Comment: A few years later and just blanking out `ADMINS` remains the simplest fix.